# Define a custom Type that behaves like typing.Any

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy, python-dataclasses

I need to create a Type that behaves like `typing.Any` when looked at by the type checker (mypy), but is distinguishable from `typing.Any`.

The use case is some pretty "meta" code that needs to find the variable that is annotated with this type out of a set of other variables that could be annotated with `typing.Any`.
Note that I will never have to actually make an instance of this Type, I just need it for type annotations in the context of dataclasses.
Example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import Any


MyAny = ... # What to put here?

@dataclass()
class Test:

    a: Any
    b: MyAny = None


for field in fields(Test):
    if field.type == MyAny:
        print(f"It's {field.name}")   # This should print "It's b"
```

Things I have tried:

1. Doesn't work, because you can't subclass Any: `TypeError: Cannot subclass <class 'typing._SpecialForm'>`

   ```
   class MyAny(Any):
      pass
   ```
2. Doesn't work, because it is not distinguishable from the normal Any (result of code snipped above is `It's a\nIt's b`)

   ```
   MyAny = Any
   ```
3. Works at runtime, but mypy complains about the default value:
   `Mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "MyAny")`

   ```
   class MyAny:
      pass
   ```
4. Works at runtime, but mypy can't tell that this should behave like `Any`: 
   It complains about the definition that
   `Mypy: Argument 2 to NewType(...) must be subclassable(got "Any")` 
   and it complaints about the default parameter: 
   `Mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "MyAny")`

   ```
   from typing import NewType
   MyAny = NewType("MyAny", Any)
   ```

So is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Might want to take a look at Monads. Option for example is a monad which behaves like a wrapper that accepts any type. You could arguably construct your own monad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use conditionals to trick mypy into interpreting one piece of code while having your runtime execute another one.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import Any


if False:
    MyAny = Any
else:
    class MyAny:  # type: ignore
        pass


@dataclass()
class Test:

    a: Any
    b: MyAny = None


for field in fields(Test):
    if field.type == MyAny:
        print(f"It's {field.name}")   # This should print "It's b"
```

Comment: Neat, actually even better I can import typing.TYPE_CHECKING and test for if TYPE_CHECKING

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar).

```
# foo.py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import Any, TypeVar, Generic, Optional


MyAny = TypeVar('MyAny')

@dataclass()
class Test(Generic[MyAny]):

    a: Any
    b: Optional[MyAny] = None

for field in fields(Test):
    if field.type == Optional[MyAny]:
        print(f"It's {field.name}")
```

Output

```plaintext
$ python3 foo.py 
It's b
 
$ mypy foo.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: This kind of  works, but mypy complains that "Type Variable MyAny is unbound".
 But if I define `_MyAny = TypeVar("_MyAny")` 
`MyAny = Optional[_MyAny]`, mypy complaints about the comparison `if field.type == MyAny` "The type alias to Union is invalid in runtime context".
What works is to check against `Optional[_MyAny]`

Comment: Without `Generic[MyAny]`, `MyAny` will not be bound in the class `Test`. Or are you referring to a different issue?

Comment: It complains even with `Optional[_MyAny]` that it is unbound.
If I alias `MyAny = Optional[_MyAny]` and then define `b: MyAny` but check against `field.type == Optional[_MyAny]`, it works without errors. That is a good enough solution at the moment, because I can hide that behind implementation details. I am curious why that is the case though.